# SSL/TLS secure channel issues

Tags: ssl, wireshark, tls1.2

I'm connecting to a server using TLS 1.2 SRV 2K12 R2 but ultimately getting the dreaded "COULD NOT CREATE SSL/TLS SECURE CHANNEL". I was wondering if it'd be possible to figure out the reason via Wireshark. I'm only getting the Client\Server Hello and then the Public cert exchange.

The other end fully supports TLS 1.0,1.1 and 1.2 and has A ratings on SSLLABS albeit using a SHA1 cert.

The following are wireshark output: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yxjk3rj0lyclyn4/AADxGu6Q4tT6mzPXMJge7IGLa?dl=0

I also scanned both sides using SSLSCAN:

```
them
Supported Server Cipher(s):
    Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  256 bits  AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-SHA256
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  AES128-SHA256
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA

  Preferred Server Cipher(s):
    SSLv2  0 bits    (NONE)
    SSLv3  0 bits    (NONE)
    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    TLS11  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    TLS12  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

me

 Supported Server Cipher(s):
    Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  256 bits  AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-SHA256
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  AES128-SHA256
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA

  Preferred Server Cipher(s):
    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    TLS11  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    TLS12  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
```

Comment: The information are incomplete and this way probably hide the problem. The ServerHello packet is 1460 bytes but your Dropbox download is cut after the first ServerHello part (99 bytes). Apart from that it is much better offer the full pcap instead of just selected text information. With the pcap one could see for example who closes the connection. Also, there seems to be a firewall device involved (Fortinet) so this might cause trouble.

Comment: Ill add the full pcap then

Comment: I uploaded the full pcap to the same link.

Comment: According to the pcap the client closes the connection the hard way (i.e. with a RST). From the ClientHello and ServerHello everything looks fine so  the problem must be somewhere inside your **unknown** client.